# What is boot line in BSP

Tags: bsp

On the wikipedia page [Board support package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package) it mentions the term "boot line". What is the meaning of "boot line"?

Comment: That's a term from the "example" section, and it's specific to the VXWorks/WindRiver bootloader. It's not a universal term. It's probably the equivalent of a "kernel command line" in Linux/lilu/GRUB terminology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a program from a command prompt on a desktop operating system, you can add extra command line parameters after the name of the program.  This provides a mechanism to push parameters into the program being run.

The "boot line" in VxWorks provides similar functionality.  It allows parameters to be passed into the VxWorks application being booted.